# Is there any rule of law for selecting a feature from highly correlated ones?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, feature-selection

For example, considering the [Breast Cancer Wisconsin (Diagnostic) Data Set](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/breast-cancer-wisconsin-data), and computing features correlations (after label-encoding the only categorical feature: `diagnosis`).

```py
corr = data.corr()
# correlation between first 5 features
corr.iloc[:, : 5].head()

                diagnosis   radius_mean texture_mean    perimeter_mean  area_mean
diagnosis       1.000000     0.730029    0.415185          0.742636     0.708984
radius_mean     0.730029     1.000000    0.323782          0.997855     0.987357
texture_mean    0.415185     0.323782    1.000000          0.329533     0.321086
perimeter_mean  0.742636     0.997855    0.329533          1.000000     0.986507
area_mean       0.708984     0.987357    0.321086          0.986507     1.000000
```

Suppose we consider two features that have a correlation higher than 0.9, and select one one. We can say in this case that 3 features are highly correlated.

```
radius_mean - perimeter_mean: 0.997855
radius_mean - area_mean:      0.987357
perimeter_mean - area_mean:   0.986507
```

In selecting 1 out of these 3, is there any rule or suggestion recommemded in feature selection (for instance one with min/max corr value etc...)?

Comment: You have a choice: (a) use expert knowledge (for a circle, geometry tells you circumference is proportional to radius but not to area, and one of these may be medically more relevant for cancer diagnosis); (b) get your machine to make choices for you as it can do for example with lasso regularisation; or (c) do some manual fix looking at arbitrary numbers.  I would have thought (c) is not the best approach.

Comment: What is the aim of the study? Achieveing the highest possible accuracy in diagnosis?

Comment: @The_old_man well this example is just to help explain my question. In my actual problem dataset, is a prediction task for multiclass classification.

Comment: Most of the times,the best answer is the expert opinion. Relying on other statistical indices can lead to overfitting. In your example, these variables are all mathematically related and highly correlated so it doesn't really matter which one you choose. It does depend on your classification model as well and which method you applied.